# How to programmatically reMeasure view?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have `CustomView` with 2 `RelativeLayouts`. There are `RecyclerViews` in each `RelativeLayout`. When I add new element to `RecyclerView` it doesn`t change height.

If I change screen orientation then android measures it well. So my question is how to programmatically tell android that he needs remeasure both childs and parent elements.

`requestlayout()` and `invalidate()` doesn`t work

**CustomView:**

```
public class ExpandableView extends LinearLayout {


    private Settings mSettings ;
    private int mExpandState;
    private ValueAnimator mExpandAnimator;
    private ValueAnimator mParentAnimator;
    private AnimatorSet mExpandScrollAnimatorSet;
    private  int mExpandedViewHeight;
    private  boolean mIsInit = true;
    private int defaultHeight;

    private boolean isAllowedExpand = false;

    private ScrolledParent mScrolledParent;
    private OnExpandListener mOnExpandListener;


    public ExpandableView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init(null);

    }

    public ExpandableView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);

    }

    public ExpandableView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        Log.w("tag", "init");
        setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        this.setClipChildren(false);
        this.setClipToPadding(false);

        mExpandState = ExpandState.PRE_INIT;
        mSettings = new Settings();
        if(attrs!=null) {
            TypedArray typedArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ExpandableView);
            mSettings.expandDuration = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.ExpandableView_expDuration, Settings.EXPAND_DURATION);
            mSettings.expandWithParentScroll = typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.ExpandableView_expWithParentScroll,false);
            mSettings.expandScrollTogether = typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.ExpandableView_expExpandScrollTogether,true);
            typedArray.recycle();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        Log.w("tag", "onMeasure");
        Log.w("tag", "widthMeasureSpec - " + widthMeasureSpec);
        Log.w("tag", "heightMeasureSpec - " + heightMeasureSpec);
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        if(childCount!=2) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ExpandableLayout must has two child view !");
        }
        if(mIsInit) {

            ((MarginLayoutParams)getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin=0;
            MarginLayoutParams marginLayoutParams = ((MarginLayoutParams)getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams());
            marginLayoutParams.bottomMargin=0;
            marginLayoutParams.topMargin=0;
            marginLayoutParams.height = 0;
            mExpandedViewHeight = getChildAt(1).getMeasuredHeight();
            defaultHeight = mExpandedViewHeight;

            mIsInit =false;
            mExpandState = ExpandState.CLOSED;
            View view = getChildAt(0);
            if (view != null){
                view.setOnClickListener(v -> toggle());
            }
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        Log.w("tag", "onSizeChanged");
        if(mSettings.expandWithParentScroll) {
            mScrolledParent = Utils.getScrolledParent(this);
        }
    }

    private int getParentScrollDistance () {
        int distance = 0;
        Log.w("tag", "getParentScrollDistance");
        if(mScrolledParent == null) {
            return distance;
        }
        distance = (int) (getY() + getMeasuredHeight() + mExpandedViewHeight - mScrolledParent.scrolledView.getMeasuredHeight());
        for(int index = 0; index < mScrolledParent.childBetweenParentCount; index++) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getParent();
            distance+=parent.getY();
        }

        return distance;
    }

    private void verticalAnimate(final int startHeight, final int endHeight ) {
        int distance = getParentScrollDistance();  

        final View target = getChildAt(1);

        mExpandAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(startHeight,endHeight);
        mExpandAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                target.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                target.requestLayout();
            }
        });

        mExpandAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                if(endHeight-startHeight < 0) {
                    mExpandState = ExpandState.CLOSED;
                    if (mOnExpandListener != null) {
                        mOnExpandListener.onExpand(false);
                    }
                } else {
                    mExpandState=ExpandState.EXPANDED;
                    if(mOnExpandListener != null) {
                        mOnExpandListener.onExpand(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        mExpandState=mExpandState==ExpandState.EXPANDED?ExpandState.CLOSING :ExpandState.EXPANDING;

        mExpandAnimator.setDuration(mSettings.expandDuration);

        if(mExpandState == ExpandState.EXPANDING && mSettings.expandWithParentScroll && distance > 0) {

            mParentAnimator = Utils.createParentAnimator(mScrolledParent.scrolledView, distance, mSettings.expandDuration);

            mExpandScrollAnimatorSet = new AnimatorSet();

            if(mSettings.expandScrollTogether) {
                mExpandScrollAnimatorSet.playTogether(mExpandAnimator,mParentAnimator);
            } else {
                mExpandScrollAnimatorSet.playSequentially(mExpandAnimator,mParentAnimator);
            }
            mExpandScrollAnimatorSet.start();

        } else {
            mExpandAnimator.start();
        }


    }

    public void setExpand(boolean expand) {
        if (mExpandState == ExpandState.PRE_INIT) {return;}

        getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = expand ? mExpandedViewHeight : 0;
        requestLayout();
        mExpandState=expand?ExpandState.EXPANDED:ExpandState.CLOSED;
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return mExpandState==ExpandState.EXPANDED;
    }

    public void toggle() {
        if (isAllowedExpand){
            if(mExpandState==ExpandState.EXPANDED) {
                close();
            }else if(mExpandState==ExpandState.CLOSED) {
                expand();
            }
        }
    }

    public void expand() {
        verticalAnimate(0,mExpandedViewHeight);
    }

    public void close() {
        verticalAnimate(mExpandedViewHeight,0);
    }

    public interface OnExpandListener {
        void onExpand(boolean expanded) ;
    }

    public void setOnExpandListener(OnExpandListener onExpandListener) {
        this.mOnExpandListener = onExpandListener;
    }


    public void setExpandScrollTogether(boolean expandScrollTogether) {
        this.mSettings.expandScrollTogether = expandScrollTogether;
    }

    public void setExpandWithParentScroll(boolean expandWithParentScroll) {
        this.mSettings.expandWithParentScroll = expandWithParentScroll;
    }

    public void setExpandDuration(int expandDuration) {
        this.mSettings.expandDuration = expandDuration;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        Log.w("tag", "onDetachedFromWindow");
        if(mExpandAnimator!=null&&mExpandAnimator.isRunning()) {
            mExpandAnimator.cancel();
            mExpandAnimator.removeAllUpdateListeners();
        }
        if(mParentAnimator!=null&&mParentAnimator.isRunning()) {
            mParentAnimator.cancel();
            mParentAnimator.removeAllUpdateListeners();
        }
        if(mExpandScrollAnimatorSet!=null) {
            mExpandScrollAnimatorSet.cancel();
        }
    }

    public void setAllowedExpand(boolean allowedExpand) {
        isAllowedExpand = allowedExpand;
    }

    public void increaseDistance(int size){

        if(mExpandState==ExpandState.EXPANDED) {
            close();
        }

        mExpandedViewHeight = defaultHeight + size;

    }


//func just for loggs
    public void showParams(){

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) getChildAt(1);
        /*relativeLayout.requestLayout();
        relativeLayout.invalidate();*/



        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) relativeLayout.getChildAt(1);

        Log.d("tag", "height - " + relativeLayout.getHeight());
        Log.d("tag", "childs - " +  relativeLayout.getChildCount());
        Log.d("tag", "recycler height - " +   recyclerView.getHeight());

        recyclerView.requestLayout();
        recyclerView.invalidateItemDecorations();
        recyclerView.invalidate();


        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        layoutManager.getHeight();



        Log.d("tag", " layoutManager.getHeight() - " + layoutManager.getHeight());
        layoutManager.requestLayout();
        layoutManager.generateDefaultLayoutParams();
        layoutManager.onItemsChanged(recyclerView);


        Log.d("tag", " layoutManager.getHeight()2- " + layoutManager.getHeight());


        layoutManager.getChildCount();
        recyclerView.getChildCount();
        Log.d("tag", "manager childs - " + layoutManager.getChildCount());
        Log.d("tag", "recycler childs - " + recyclerView.getChildCount());
    }
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/grey_light_color"
    >


    <com.example.develop.project.Utils.ExpandableView.ExpandableView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/test_custom_view"
        app:expWithParentScroll="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/grey_color"

        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/start_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@color/white_color"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/stage_tv4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_deep_color"
                    android:text="Запуск"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:textSize="18sp"

                    />



            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/start_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/start_accept"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_deep_color"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"

                />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/my_test_tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/start_tv"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    >

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </RelativeLayout>



    </com.example.develop.project.Utils.ExpandableView.ExpandableView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Add elem"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/check_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Check params"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity:**

```
public class TestActivity extends MvpAppCompatActivity implements TestContract.View {


    TestAdapter testAdapter;

    @InjectPresenter
    public TestPresenter presenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        ExpandableView expandableView = findViewById(R.id.test_custom_view);
        expandableView.setAllowedExpand(true);

        Button add_btn = findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
        Button check_btn = findViewById(R.id.check_btn);




        add_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                presenter.addElem();

            }
        });

        check_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                expandableView.showParams();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void addElems(ArrayList<String> list) {

        testAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void populateAdapter(ArrayList<String> list) {

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.my_test_tv);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);



        testAdapter = new TestAdapter(list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(testAdapter);
    }
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.TasksViewHolder> {
    private List<String> list;

    public TestAdapter(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TestAdapter.TasksViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.test_item, parent, false);

        TestAdapter.TasksViewHolder vh = new TestAdapter.TasksViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TestAdapter.TasksViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String text = list.get(position);


        holder.textView.setText(text);

    }


    public static class TasksViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;


        public TasksViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_test_tv);

        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just quick but important check: you aren't calling setHasFixedSize(true) on your reclycerview, are you?

Comment: @JosefAdamcik sure, I don`t call setHasFixedSize

Comment: @JosefAdamcik after adding new element in RecyclerView I call getHeight and it doesn`t change, so I think that I have:
1) change size recyclerview
2) change all parents size step by step

Comment: 442 Actually it should work automatically. I suppose there must be either some problem in your layout (e.g. wrong value of layout_height somewhere) or something wrong with your custom view. Try: a) use layout inspector and explore hiearchy, you may spot something interesteing, b) replace custom view with smth. else to check if it works in "normal" situation. This will help you to narrow down source of your problem. c) post your layout and more info about (or code of)  your customview in order to have higher chance of getting help on StackOverflow

Comment: @JosefAdamcik thank you for your advices.
a) I think that problem isn`t related to layout in my case
b) I checked recyclers w/o customview and in another situatios, but it works well
c) added code

Answer (score 2):

The ExpandableView contains some suspicious code in its `onMeasure` method.

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    ...
    if(mIsInit) {

        ((MarginLayoutParams)getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin=0;
        MarginLayoutParams marginLayoutParams = ((MarginLayoutParams)getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams());
        marginLayoutParams.bottomMargin=0;
        marginLayoutParams.topMargin=0;
        marginLayoutParams.height = 0;
        mExpandedViewHeight = getChildAt(1).getMeasuredHeight();
        defaultHeight = mExpandedViewHeight;

        mIsInit =false;
        mExpandState = ExpandState.CLOSED;
        View view = getChildAt(0);
        if (view != null){
            view.setOnClickListener(v -> toggle());
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

The `mIsInit` variable is set to `true` on creation and than to `false` when `onMeasure` is called for the first time. So the code in the condition runs only once.

But it stores value `mExpandedViewHeight` obtained as `getChildAt(1).getMeasuredHeight()` and that is current height of your relative layout, which contains (still empty) RecyclerView.

As far as I can see there's nothing in ExpadableView's code that would update this value, when you add an item to the Recylerview.

I am not sure, what would the correct/perfect implementation of the `onMeasure` method be (for your component). That would require some debugging and testing of the component, and perhaps some tweaks in other parts of the code.

If you wrote the component, you may want to invest more effort into debugging. If you didn't write the component, you should try to find other one, that is properly implemented. Custom components with custom measurements are an advanced topic.

If you really want to go with debugging and fixing your component, that first thing to do is to update the `mExpandedViewHeight` value on every measurement, but that might require updating other values that are derived from this value.